# Display Title message when hover textarea in Jsp using struts application resource properties

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, struts-1

How to use application resource properties values for the Jsp.

```
<span id="####aaa">
            <html:textarea title=""   />
</span>
```

When mouse is over the text area .It will display the title value which is coming from applicationresource.properties file

---

ApplicationResource.Properties

abcd.text.value= Hello 
defg.text.value= Hey

By using bean message key in the struts like:

```
<bean:message key='<%="abcd.text.value"%>'/>
```

How we use this in title for the JSP textarea ?

Any suggestions for this is appreciable!!!!